When using incremental stats, some partitions are missing stats objects
I am trying to use incremental stats on a partitioned table to make it easier to manage statistics updates for a very large table. I am seeing some behavior that some partitions are not getting statistics objects. Even if I issue UPDATE STATISTICS ... WITH RESAMPLE ON PARTITIONS(X, Y, Z), those partitions still do not get statistics objects.
This has led to a real problem in the wild where the table-level histogram step was missing one of the partitions and also had RANGE_ROWS = 0, leading the optimizer to think a partition was empty when it was not.
Here is a script that can recreate the behavior. The partitions that are missing stats seem to change every time you run it so maybe it is nondeterministic which partitions get stats.
I am on SQL Server 2022 CU13.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.MissingIncrementalStatsTable;

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1
              FROM sys.partition_schemes
              WHERE name = N'MissingIncrementalStatsScheme' )
BEGIN
  DROP PARTITION SCHEME MissingIncrementalStatsScheme;
END;

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1
              FROM sys.partition_functions
              WHERE name = N'MissingIncrementalStatsFunction' )
BEGIN
  DROP PARTITION FUNCTION MissingIncrementalStatsFunction;
END;

SELECT @@VERSION;

DECLARE @sSql             nvarchar(MAX),
        @iTotalPartitions int          = 500, /* 500 is a guarantee to get it to happen, can happen with fewer */
        @sBoundaryPoints  nvarchar(MAX);

/* create partition function */
SELECT @sBoundaryPoints = STRING_AGG( CONVERT( nvarchar(MAX), Number ), N', ' )
  FROM( SELECT TOP( @iTotalPartitions )
               1000 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY( SELECT NULL )) Number
          FROM master..spt_values t1
            CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2 ) Numbers;
SET @sSql = N'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION MissingIncrementalStatsFunction( bigint )
                AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES( ' + @sBoundaryPoints + N' );';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSql;

/* create partition scheme */
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME MissingIncrementalStatsScheme
  AS PARTITION MissingIncrementalStatsFunction
  ALL TO ( [DEFAULT] );

/* create table */
CREATE TABLE dbo.MissingIncrementalStatsTable
(
  id        bigint NOT NULL,
  some_data nvarchar(50)
) ON MissingIncrementalStatsScheme (id);

/* add PK with incremental stats*/
ALTER TABLE dbo.MissingIncrementalStatsTable
ADD CONSTRAINT MissingIncrementalStats_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED( id )WITH( STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL = ON )ON MissingIncrementalStatsScheme(id);

/* get data in the table, 1000 rows per partition */
INSERT INTO dbo.MissingIncrementalStatsTable WITH( TABLOCKX )
( id, some_data )
  SELECT TOP( @iTotalPartitions * 1000 - 1 )
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY( SELECT NULL )),
         REPLICATE( N'Z', 50 )
    FROM master..spt_values t1
      CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2;

/* build some stats */
UPDATE STATISTICS MissingIncrementalStatsTable
  WITH INCREMENTAL = ON;

/* if we do find partitions without stats, issue RESAMPLE ON PARTITIONS for those partitions*/
DECLARE @sInPartitionList nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @sInPartitionList = STRING_AGG( CONVERT( nvarchar(MAX), partition_number ), N', ' )
  FROM sys.dm_db_incremental_stats_properties( OBJECT_ID( N'MissingIncrementalStatsTable' ), 1 )
  WHERE last_updated IS NULL;

SET @sSql = N'UPDATE STATISTICS MissingIncrementalStatsTable 
              WITH INCREMENTAL = ON,
                   RESAMPLE ON PARTITIONS (' + @sInPartitionList + N')';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSql;

/* find all the partitions without stats objects and count how many rows are in them */
SET @sSql = N'
SELECT $partition.MissingIncrementalStatsFunction(id) partition_number, 
       COUNT_BIG( * ) total_rows
  FROM dbo.MissingIncrementalStatsTable
  WHERE $partition.MissingIncrementalStatsFunction(id) IN ( ' + @sInPartitionList + N')
  GROUP BY $partition.MissingIncrementalStatsFunction(id)
  ORDER BY partition_number;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSql;

/* still see missing stats */
SELECT *
  FROM sys.dm_db_incremental_stats_properties( OBJECT_ID( N'MissingIncrementalStatsTable' ), 1 )
  WHERE last_updated IS NULL
  ORDER BY partition_number;

Is this just "the way it works"? I can't find anything in the documentation saying that if you use incremental statistics that you are guaranteed that every partition will get its own stats but also it seems odd that they wouldn't. Odder still is that UPDATE STATISTICS ... WITH RESAMPLE ON PARTITIONS would not create statistics objects for the specified partitions.
